# Order by field in subdocument in array of document?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents like the following:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  Sc: [
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 1
    },
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-02T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 2
    },
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-03T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 3
    },
  ]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  Sc: [
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 100
    },
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-02T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 200
    },
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-03T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 300
    },
  ]
},
{
  _id: 3,
  Sc: [
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 1
    },
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-02T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 2
    },
    {
      Ts: ISODate("2017-01-03T10:00:00.000+0000"),
      Sc: 3000
    },
  ]
}
```

I'd like to sort the documents on the *last* element in the Sc array (By TS, not necessarily physically last)'s Sc field, descending. So, the resulting documents should be in reverse order of the example above (_id's of 3, 2, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate with `$unwind` to perform an array deconstruction.
Then you can select minTs and sort by minTs desc.

```js
db.colls.aggregate([
  {$unwind: {path: "$Sc"}}, 
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', minTs: {$min: '$Sc.Ts'}}}, 
  {$sort: {minTs: -1}}
])
```

```json
{ "_id" : 3, "minTs" : ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "minTs" : ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 1, "minTs" : ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00Z") }
```

With this solution you lose the initial Sc array but it will be lighter for transfers.

If you want to keep it, you can use a previous `$project` to save Sc in an initialSc value and use it in an other `$project` at the end :

```js
db.colls.aggregate([{
  $project: {Sc: 1, initialSc: '$Sc'}}, 
  {$unwind: {path: "$Sc"}}, 
  {$group: {_id: { _id: '$_id', Sc: '$initialSc'}, minTs: {$min: '$Sc.Ts'}}}, 
  {$sort: {minTs: -1}}, 
  {$project: {_id: '$_id._id', Sc: '$_id.Sc'}}])
```

```json
{ "_id" : 3, "Sc" : [
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 1 }, 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-02T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 2 }, 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-03T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 3000 }
] }
{ "_id" : 2, "Sc" : [
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 100 }, 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-02T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 200 }, 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-03T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 300 }
] }
{ "_id" : 1, "Sc" : [ 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-01T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 1 }, 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-02T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 2 }, 
  { "Ts" : ISODate("2017-01-03T10:00:00Z"), "Sc" : 3 } 
] }
```